# Are hemp, flax, chia, and sesame generally raw?

Tags: raw, seeds

Are hemp, flax, chia, and sesame generally sold raw, or is heating processing used to isolate these seeds?

Comment: In which country? The laws and practices are likely to vary between different countries.

Comment: @Nic United States

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like heat processing (Pasteurization) is normally used for all of these seeds, unless otherwise marked.

---

#### Hemp seeds (hemp hearts)

One brain [claims](https://www.purehealingfoods.com/hempHeartsFAQ.php) that many other brands of hemp seeds are heat-sterilized. This is supported by an [answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Does-imported-hemp-seed-that-is-sterilized-for-consumption-in-the-U-S-retain-its-nutritional-value-How-are-hemp-seeds-sterilized) which indicates that hemp seeds imported into the United States are sterilized.

#### Flax seeds

This [2015 article on NPR](https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2015/05/19/407760579/what-does-raw-mean-when-it-comes-to-almonds-you-might-be-surprised) explains about a warehouse that performs heat treatment on flax and chia seeds.

#### Chia seeds

See above about NPR article.

#### Sesame seeds

This [random webpage](http://www.wellnesstips.ca/pasteurized%20almonds.htm) claims that there is no such thing as a raw sesame seed.